# can't change partition permissions in linux in a dual boot system

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu Budgie on my laptop (dual boot). Windows is on a 1TB HDD drive and Linux (which I mostly use) is on a separate SSD. Previously, I could access my HDD from Windows with all permissions but recently I used the free version of [IM-Magic Partition Resizer Free](https://www.resize-c.com/) in Windows to change and merge some partitions. Now, the problem is that I lost my write-execute permission on Linux!

```
cp: cannot create regular file './nima2.ovpn': Read-only file system
```

I tried some commands I found on the web and his site but none worked. I also tried [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) but couldn't make it work.

Here is the data of one of my partitions:

[image: Partition Information Screen Capture]

Here is the content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb during installation
UUID=f3194103-518f-4b51-b3ee-0df649359852 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=B084-4E87  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=b337eac3-ac75-44cb-9175-cd9c3dd2b6a9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Please edit you post to include the content of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @SerafimDahl added to the post

Comment: Try rebooting your windows (not shutting down) and retry. I had the same problem and that was caused by some metadata or something like that which is flushed by Windows only if you reboot it.And if the linux is unable to get those metadata , it cannot mount the filesystem with RW permissions.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi tnx, but since it's a dual boot systems. when restart my windows system, I still have to choose windows in the grub menu. Does this affect the rebooting operation?

Comment: There is no entry in `/etc/fstab` for the NTFS partition that you want to access. I would find the NTFS Volume Serial Number and create an entry in `/etc/fstab`. Even so, if windows is not shut down but just hybernating, then Linux will only mount the NTFS partition as read only so windows has to be shut down to get read/write permission on an NTFS partition.

Comment: @SerafimDahl In fact it has to be **rebooted**(i.e soft-reboot) not shutdown.But I have to say that I tried that almost one year ago.The situation might have changed in the past few months.I don't know.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri No that doesn't matter.Just make sure each time you want to boot linux (and also write into your windows' partition) the Windows is rebooted first.

Answer (score 1):

I have a NTFS volume that is automounted when the computer starts. In `/etc/fstab` there is the following entry:

```
UUID=BC2E8B1A2E8ACD38 /mnt/win ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

where BC2E8B1A2E8ACD38 is the NTFS Volume Serial Number which can be found (in my case) with `blkid /dev/sdc1` which gives the output:

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="BC2E8B1A2E8ACD38" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6dbd7f38-fe9e-4eb5-9769-2803188075b8"
```

I haven't tried to mount it by the `PARTUUID`. Also, the umask=000 is not recommended as it gives full read/write permissions to anyone but I'm the only one that can log in to the computer. `uid` and `gid` are my user and group ID.
(I will sharpen `umask` to `002`)

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: I suppose I meant it as an answer to the question. Had it been a question I would have phrased it differently AND started a new thread.